# how to customize my logo and slider in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am beginner in WordPress ,I had put all html code of my header in to my header.php file ,but I need  logo and slider images changeable from admin site .how to customize my logo and slider ?

Answer (score 0):

What theme are you using? Mostly you can change both of the things u mentioned under tab "apearence" and then select "header" or "theme options".

Comment: I am using twenty twelve

Comment: so then u can use the tab "header" under "appearence" to change it, right?

Comment: Yes , I know but I cant do that ,because I need to 1st remove my html code and put there wordpress custom code in place of  my my logo and slider code to change my logo and slider I think

Comment: I also know there is one plugin  advance custom filed this give me facility like that ,but its not working

Comment: I dont get it, can u edit ur post and add your header.php code? Maybe then i can understand what u mean

Comment: I think you never convert html to wordpress or you are not understand my question right ?

Comment: post ur header.php and all the things u custom editted, maybe i can help u from there

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the

> login_enqueue_scripts

hook to insert some custom CSS into the head of your page so you can show your logo instead.

You may refer to this PHP example, for a login page, on snip2code [- How to customize the WordPress Login Logo](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/16236/How-to-customize-the-WordPress-Login-Log?fromPage=1)